# turn a firebase database value into an Int

Tags: swift, firebase, casting, firebase-realtime-database

In my app people can make bets on which team they think will win. When they go to make a bet a couple of things should be uploaded to the database. First the username of the person making the bet. Which bet this is( is it bet one bet two bet three) and it should show what team the bet is for.

The problem I have turning the bet into an Int so that I can increment it every time someone makes a bet so that they have a unique bet.

below I have a couple of things that I will explain because my code is jumbled up at the moment because of testing purposes.

in the viewDidLoad method I have the means to gather the user name and how many bets that someone has made. in the database this defaults as a string "0".

now bet self.betNumber should have the value "0"

then in the submitData function I safely take the betNumber and turn it into an Int then assign that value to the globally declared variable bets

then I increment bets by 1
after that I try to cast self.bets into a String and but it into the database as a child

and this is where I get an error

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import Firebase


class addBets: UIViewController {
    let betRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL: "not showing these sorry")
    let userRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL: "")
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL: "")
    let currentUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser


    @IBOutlet weak var teamOneLabelAdd: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var teamTwoLabelAdd: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var teamOneBet: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var teamTwoBet: UITextField!



    var userName: String!
    var teamOne: String!
    var teamTwo = String()

    var betNumber: String!
    var bets: Int = 0




    var teamOneBetAnotherOne: String!
    var teamOneBetAnotherTwo: String!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        teamOneLabelAdd.text = teamOne
        teamTwoLabelAdd.text = teamTwo


        //Looks for single or multiple taps.
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")

        //Uncomment the line below if you want the tap not not interfere and cancel other interactions.
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false

        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        //self.teamOneBet.delegate = self
        //self.teamTwoBet.delegate = self

        let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
        ref.child("User").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            // Get user value
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let username = value?["username"] as? String ?? ""
            self.userName = username
            let betnumber = value?["bets"] as? String ?? ""
            self.betNumber = betnumber




            // ...
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }


    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(userText: UITextField!) -> Bool {
        teamOneBet.resignFirstResponder()
        teamTwoBet.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }


    func dismissKeyboard() {
        //Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.
        view.endEditing(true)
    }

    @IBAction func submitData(_ sender: Any) {
        // get the userName to tell who is doing the bet and set it as a key

        sleep(4)

        if let usernamee = self.userName {
            if let anotherBet = self.betNumber as? Int {
                self.bets = anotherBet
            }
            self.bets += 1

            let usableBets = self.bets as? String ?? ""

            let useRef = self.ref.child("Bets").child(usernamee).child(self.bets as? String ?? "")

            var values = ["Username": usernamee,"Bet": "0", "ForTeam": ""]
            if let betOne = self.teamOneBet.text{

                if betOne == "" {

                } else {
                    values["Bet"] = betOne
                    values["ForTeam"] = teamOneLabelAdd.text
                }
            }
            if let betTwo = self.teamTwoBet.text{

                if betTwo == "" {

                } else {
                    values["Bet"] = betTwo
                    values["ForTeam"] = teamTwoLabelAdd.text
                }
            }


        //self.betRef.child("Bets").setValue(self.userName)
        if let worked = currentUser?.getTokenWithCompletion() {

            useRef.setValue(values)
            /*
            useRef.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in
                if (error != nil) {
                    print(error!)
                    return

                }

            })
            */



        }


         self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

        }







    }

    func getUserName() {
        let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
        ref.child("User").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            // Get user value
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let username = value?["username"] as? String ?? ""
            self.userName = username

            // ...
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        //let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        //var DestViewController : addBets = segue.destination as! addBets
        //DestViewController.teamOne = self.teamOne.text!
        //DestViewController.teamOne = self.teamTTwo

        if segue.identifier == "gotobetview" {
            if let destination = segue.destination as? BetView {

                //destination.userNames = self.teamOne.text! as? String

                //destination.teamTwo = (self.teamTwo.text! as? String)!
            }
        }

    }

}
```

and here is the firebase structure the data I am extracting is coming from the "User" and the data I am writing to is "Bets"

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a cursory look at your code, it looks like the error is in this line:

```
let useRef = self.ref.child("Bets").child(usernamee).child(self.bets as? String ?? "")
```

I am not entirely sure where you want to be posting the bets a user makes, but what that does is it sets `useRef` to a child located at `Bets.\(usernamee).1` when the bet is 1, and `Bets.\(usernamee).2` when the bet is 2, etc.

If you want each bet to be unique, you can simply change `useRef` to this:

```
let useRef = self.ref.child("Bets").child(usernamee).childByAutoId()
```

This will create a new entry in firebase that looks something like this:

```
Bets:
    usernameyoyo:
        -Kfx81GvUxoHpmmMwJ9P:
            Bet: "300",
            ForTeam: "Natus Vincere",
            Username: "usernameyoyo"
```

---

So now the question is how to get the bets that are made?  Well this is actually quite simple now that each one is uniquely identified:

```
func getBetsFor(_ username: String) {
    ref.child("Bets".child(username).observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        //
        // this is the unique identifier of the bet.  eg, -Kfx81GvUxoHpmmMwJ9P
        let betId = snapshot.key as String

        guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyHashable] else {
            print("failed to get dictionary from Bets.\(username)")
            return
        }

        let bet = dict["Bet"] as? String
        let forTeam = dict["ForTeam"] as? String


        // do something with the above information!

    })
}
```

Comment: let me post my firebase structure real quick @ForestKunecke

Comment: yeah I think the (usernamee).1 would be right. I just need each bet to be unique

Comment: can you show an example of how to use this I have never used this kind of thing in swift

Comment: I don't know if that would work because I would need to get the data later and I don't know how I would read a random number @ForestKunecke

Comment: if you replace that definition of `useRef` with the one I provided, you should get a firebase structure that looks like the one in my answer.  With that your bets are guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: yes but would you know how to read a auto id to get the data inside I can't exactly look it up every time someone makes a bet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139108/discussion-between-forest-kunecke-and-devin-tripp).

Comment: Ok this looks as if this will work sorry the documentation on firebase leaves this kind of stuff out. I will go ahead and say this is the correct answer.